# Having trouble getting docker to work on mac

Tags: macos, docker

OK so here is what I have done so far. I installed docker for mac, and that worked fine. From there I tried to get a project up and running using `docker-compose` and I got the following error:

```
Could not read CA certificate "/Users/<useraccountfolder>/.boot2docker/certs/boot2docker-vm/ca.pem": open /Users/<useraccountfolder>/.boot2docker/certs/boot2docker-vm/ca.pem: no such file or directory
```

So I tried to fix it by trying [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33583734/keep-getting-could-not-read-ca-certificate-when-trying-to-start-docker) accepted answer. This is when I got another error, `Host does not exist: “default”`. This is when I trie [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34785064/rails-docker-host-does-not-exist-default) accepted answer, but when I tried to run `docker-machine create default`, I got this error: `Error with pre-create check: "VBoxManage not found. Make sure VirtualBox is installed and VBoxManage is in the path"`. I am just lost at this point. Any help?

Comment: Do you have VirtualBox installed?

Comment: Shouldn't that come with the docker installer?

Comment: I followed these instructions to install it. https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/install/#install-and-run-docker-for-mac

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so I found a solution which is probably not fixing the root issue, but it does work. To unset previous variables I ran this command `unset ${!DOCKER*}`. This worked, but then I had to run it every time I started a new terminal session, so I added it to my `.bash_profile` and now I am good.

Answer (score 0):

To use docker machine you need the latest version of VirtualBox, from the docker docs:

IF YOU ARE USING DOCKER FOR MAC

Docker for Mac uses HyperKit, a lightweight macOS virtualization solution built on top of the Hypervisor.framework in macOS 10.10 Yosemite and higher.

Currently, there is no docker-machine create driver for HyperKit, so you will use virtualbox driver to create local machines. (See the Docker Machine driver for Oracle VirtualBox.) Note that you can run both HyperKit and Oracle VirtualBox on the same system. To learn more, see Docker for Mac vs. Docker Toolbox.

Make sure you have the latest VirtualBox correctly installed on your system (either as part of an earlier Toolbox install, or manual install).

Source: https://docs.docker.com/machine/get-started/#prerequisite-information

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/docker-toolbox/#the-docker-for-mac-environment it would seem that docker for mac does not need virtualbox.

Comment: Did you install Docker for Mac, or Docker Toolbox? You said that you installed Docker for Mac, which doesn't include VirtualBox.

Comment: I installed docker for mac which based on my understanding doesn't need virtualbox.

Comment: Docker for mac doesn't need VirtualBox, but docker-machine does for OSX. Since you used `docker-machine create default` you need to have VirtualBox installed as stated in https://docs.docker.com/machine/get-started/#prerequisite-information.

Comment: I only ran that command to fox the issue of host does not exist. There needs to be way to fix this issue without virtualbox.

Comment: In your question you said you were stuck on `Error with pre-create check: "VBoxManage not found. Make sure VirtualBox is installed and VBoxManage is in the path"`. Installing VirtualBox fixes this error. Maybe you can post your docker-compose so we can try to fix it without VirtualBox?